# How to give a path argument to os.walk() Python function for my Home directory?

Tags: python, paths

I want to use `os.walk()` in Python and I have to give a `path` argument to it like `os.walk(path)`. In Windows, I do it as `os.walk(c:\\)`.

What `os.walk()` does is it searches the whole `C:` directory. In Ubuntu, I want to search the whole home folder so what should be my path and how will I write it in `os.walk()`?

My code:

```
import os
from os.path import join

lookfor = "sh.txt"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('$Home\\'):

    if lookfor in files:
        print "found: %s" % join(root, lookfor)
        break
```

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on stackoverflow, and '/' is the path separator in unix, not '\'.

Comment: @psusi [Are application development questions not allowed anymore?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6554/37006)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices, pick your favorite.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser("~")
'/home/timo'
>>> os.environ["HOME"]
'/home/timo'
```

Comment: os.path.expanduser() is much more portable.